# Unity Button Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know a possible way for an animation that makes it so when a button gets clicked text pops up above the button that says [Clicked]. It must fade away after 3 seconds and it continues to go up. (The text will move up.)

Pretend like this is how it would look

Clicked but faded away

Clicked

Clicked

Clicked

### Button

(Unity Using C#)

Comment: We might have an idea as soon as you you read [ask], provide a [mcve] and tell use where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm not stuck. I just have no idea where to get started, I am a beginner and i'm trying to work on small projects and learn the basics. All I want is a button where OnClick it does that Animation.

Comment: Here some things to get you started. Create the button and text. Disable the text in editor and onbutton click run a function that enables the text, calls a coroutine on the text that moves it up (Y Axis) and fades it out and destroys at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Prefab for this?

You'd create a Prefab with a root object and a text label as a child. Then you animate the text label upwards and fading out over three seconds using the Unity animation window.

On button click, you instantiate the prefab, make it a child of the button, and position it at the same position as your button AND auto-destroy it after 3 seconds.

Here's a code example, pretending that your prefab name is "*myAnimatedText*"

```
GameObject animatedButtonText = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myAnimatedText"), transform);
animatedButtonText.transform.position = transform.position;
Destroy(animatedButtonText, 3.0f);
```